# Wordpress theme option data's missing after domain change

Tags: php, wordpress

The theme option data are missing after website domain change.I faced the issue many times,usually reenter the data ,but its not a practical solution.
I am using Options Framework plugin.

Is there any way to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom theme options framework? If so which one, a majority have an export/import option.

If you refer to the native WP Customizer, you can use this handy plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/customizer-export-import/

Please edit your question and I can update my answer to reflect this.

As you use the Options Framework Plugin, this Github thread will help you do an SQL export/import: https://github.com/devinsays/options-framework-plugin/issues/77

There’s also a fork of the theme version, where someone built the export/import functionality you require: https://github.com/vauvarin/options-framework-theme

Comment: Please read the page, specifically the section **Exporting/Importing Options**
: https://wptheming.com/options-framework-plugin/